# Area related to circles

Tags: geometry, area

A path of $4$ m width runs round a semi circular grassy plot whose circumference is $163 \frac{3}{7}$ m find the area of the path. Well my answer is around $624$ $m^2$ but I have seen completely different answers as well. Say what's yours?

Comment: Does the circumference include the diameter, or only the circular arc?

Comment: saulspatz.Yes this the question.

Comment: Includes the diameter obviously

Comment: @Arunabh Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @Arunabh If you need more details I can give it, Bye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the circumference is referred to the axis of the path we have that

- radius of the path $R=\frac{163 \frac{3}{7}}{\pi}=\frac{1144}{7\pi} m$
- area =$
     \frac{\pi(R+2)^2}{2}-\frac{\pi(R-2)^2}{2}=\frac{4576}{7}\approx 653.7
     m^2$